# Kubernetes container args behave incorrect

Tags: docker, kubernetes, postman, args, newman

I want to use Kubernetes and the `postman/newman` Docker image to execute my API tests.

Locally, I can execute the image with

> docker run postman/newman run <url-to-collection> --env-var baseUrl=<local-hostname>

I include the Image in a Kubernetes manifest file

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: newman
      image: postman/newman:latest
      args:
        - run
        - '<url-to-collection>'
        - --env-var baseUrl=<kubernetes-hostname>
```

When I apply the manifest and look at the logs of the container, I get the following error:

`error: unknown option '--global-var baseUrl=<kubernetes-hostname>'`

I tried out many things with quotes and using the `command` section instead of the `args` section, but always with the same result.
I figure that Kubernetes somehow builds the command in a way, that the `newman` executable can not understand it.
However I could not find any info about that.

(I also created an issue in the GitHub repo of Newman [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2581))

Could anybody explain to me where this problem comes from and how I might solve this?

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux commands are made up of a sequence of words.  If you type a command at a shell prompt, it takes responsibility for splitting it into words for you, but in the Kubernetes `args:` list, you need to split out the words yourself.

```yaml
args:
  - run
  - '<url-to-collection>'
  # You want these as two separate arguments, so they need to be
  # two separate list items
  - --env-var
  - baseUrl=<kubernetes-hostname>
```

If the two arguments are in the same list item, they are a single "word":

```
# /bin/ls "/app/some directory/some file"
command:
  - /bin/ls
  # a single argument, including embedded spaces
  - /app/some directory/some file
```

The same basic rules apply for Docker Compose `entrypoint:` and `command:` and the JSON-syntax Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives, except that the Docker-native forms all also accept a plain string that they will split on spaces (using a shell in the Dockerfile case, but not in the Compose case).

In the `docker run` command you provide, the shell on your host system processes it first, so the `--env-var` option and `baseUrl=...` argument get split into separate words before they're passed into the container.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this indeed solved the problem. I also had to delete the quotes around the URL, which are required when I run the command from the shell. Now it works like a charm.